# NewtonSoft JsonConverter Constructor Parameter

Tags: json, json.net, converters

I want to pass in a parameter to a Custom JsonConverter, Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
public class MySerializer: JsonConverter
{
    private object _someObject;
    public MySerializer(object someObject)
    {
       _someObject = someObject;
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MySerializer))]
public class SomeClass
{        
}
```

The problem is that I'm setting the serializer as an attribute but need the converter to have the parameter.

Comment: You mean from a JsonConverter attribute, or what?

Comment: something like ninject way of doing things.

Comment: That's pretty vague; perhaps you can edit your question to include more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry about the vagueness I hope the changes help

Comment: You could use the [`[JsonConverter(Type,Object[])]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm) override to set values for [`JsonConverterAttribute.ConverterParameters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute_ConverterParameters.htm).

Comment: What about if a the parameter is an object that needs to be initialised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that one solution could be:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MySerializer), new object())]
public class SomeClass
{

}
```